# How can I dynamically declare a set of filter criteria without having to specify the number of filters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

For example, if I have a set of data, like this:

```
var data = [ 
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 2},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 2},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 2},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 3},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 3},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 3},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 4},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 4},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 4},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 5},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 5},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 5},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 6},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 6},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 6},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 7},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 7},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 7},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 8},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 8},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 8},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 9},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 9},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 9},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 10},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 10},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 10},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 11},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 11},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 11},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 12},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 12},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 12},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1, product_id: 13},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 13},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 13},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 14},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 14},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 14},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 15},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 15},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 15},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 16},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 16},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 16},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 17},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 8, product_id: 17},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 17},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 18},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 18},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 18},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 19},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 19},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 19},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 20},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 20},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 20},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 21},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9, product_id: 21},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 21},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 22},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 22},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14, product_id: 22},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 23},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 23},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 15, product_id: 23},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 24},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 24},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 17, product_id: 24},
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 2, product_id: 25},
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 10, product_id: 25},
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 18, product_id: 25}
]
```

If I want to filter the 'product_id' with an unknown number of filters, have all the conditions together of the following dynamic array.
If I want to filter the 'product_id' with an unknown number of filters, have all the conditions together of the following dynamic array.

```
var filter = [ 
{attribute_id: 1, attribute_value_id: 1}
{attribute_id: 2, attribute_value_id: 9}
{attribute_id: 3, attribute_value_id: 14}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code.